# How to use python and telnetlib3 to send commands and provide an interactive session

Tags: python, telnet

I would like to use python to connect to a telnet server and do the following steps:

- send some commands to get the server in an initial state
- start an interactive session with stdin and stdout so a user can interact with the server's cli
- potentially send some commands after the user finishes the interactive session.

I've tried to do this in bash with telnet and netcat but it makes for a very flakey solution.

It looks like telnetlib3 is the right answer for doing this in python but there are almost no examples of how to use the classes in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - worked it out. This class, sends some commands and then presents an interactive session. Plus sends other commands if SIGTERM is detected.

```py
import asyncio
import signal
from time import sleep

import telnetlib3


class TelnetRTEMS:
    def __init__(self, hostname: str, port: int, reboot: bool, pause: bool):
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.port = port
        self.reboot = reboot
        self.pause = pause
        self.running = True
        self.terminated = False
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.terminate)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.terminate)

    def terminate(self, *args):
        self.running = False
        self.terminated = True

    async def user_input(self, writer):
        loop = asyncio.events._get_running_loop()

        while self.running:
            # run the wait for input in a separate thread
            cmd = await loop.run_in_executor(None, input)
            writer.write(cmd)
            writer.write("\r")
        writer.close()

    async def server_output(self, reader):
        while self.running:
            out_p = await reader.read(1024)
            if not out_p:
                raise EOFError("Connection closed by server")
            print(out_p, flush=True, end="")
        reader.close()

    async def shell(self, reader, writer):
        # user input and server output in separate tasks
        tasks = [
            self.server_output(reader),
            self.user_input(writer),
        ]

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    async def send_command(self, cmd):
        reader, writer = await telnetlib3.open_connection(self.hostname, self.port)

        writer.write("\r")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        prompt = await reader.read(1024)
        print(f"prompt is {prompt.strip()}")

        print(f"Sending command: {cmd}")
        writer.write(f"{cmd}\r")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        result = await reader.read(1024)
        print(f"Result is: {result.strip()}")

        reader.close()
        writer.close()

    async def connect(self):
        while True:  # retry loop
            try:
                if self.reboot:
                    print("REBOOTING IOC ...")
                    await self.send_command("exit")
                    self.reboot = False  # only reboot once
                elif self.pause:
                    print("Un-stopping IOC")
                    await self.send_command("iocRun")

                # start interactive session
                reader, writer = await telnetlib3.open_connection(
                    self.hostname, self.port, shell=self.shell
                )
                await writer.protocol.waiter_closed

                if self.terminated and self.pause:
                    print("Stopping IOC")
                    await self.send_command("iocPause")

                break  # interactive session done so exit retry loop

            except ConnectionResetError:
                # probably the previous pod is terminating and is still connected
                print("Waiting for Telnet Port (connection reset), RETRYING ...")
                sleep(3)
```